# Highcharts diamond plot avoid overlap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scatter

I am using Highcharts library to plot some diamond marker. The plot is between 2015 to 2019 month wise. As here y vaue is not available so I am using fixed point to plot the diamonds on yaxis. But this creates one problem sometimes when diamonds are closer because of nearby dates then it overlaps to each other. Now I want a solution to decide when the diamond marker should go to next level. I mean if there are 3 dates closer so the diamonds should split to three levels so that it shouldn't overlap each other. I have converted date values of xAxis in days.

Can you please suggest how to decide the level based on the days value so that I can avoid overlap.

http://jsfiddle.net/swpsw2fp/`Jsfiddle code`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcNzS.png/`Example Image`

Comment: add your code to question ,is your chart is scatterplot ?

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi I have added one example json link and the output image.

Comment: How about logic which decide which marker should be printed? Maybe better is using drilldown (like in similar column) ? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown